# Is it possible to perform a bitwise group function?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a field in a table which contains bitwise flags. Let's say for the sake of example there are three flags: `4 => read, 2 => write, 1 => execute` and the table looks like this`*`:

```
  user_id  |  file  |  permissions
-----------+--------+---------------
        1  |  a.txt |  6    ( <-- 6 = 4 + 2 = read + write)
        1  |  b.txt |  4    ( <-- 4 = 4 = read)
        2  |  a.txt |  4
        2  |  c.exe |  1    ( <-- 1 = execute)
```

I'm interested to find all users who have a particular flag set (eg: write) on ANY record. To do this in one query, I figured that if you OR'd all the user's permissions together you'd get a single value which is the "sum total" of their permissions:

```
  user_id  |  all_perms
-----------+-------------
        1  |  6        (<-- 6 | 4 = 6)
        2  |  5        (<-- 4 | 1 = 5)
```

`*`<sub>*My actual table isn't to do with files or file permissions, 'tis but an example*</sub>

Is there a way I could perform this in one statement? The way I see it, it's very similar to a normal aggregate function with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(permissions) as all_perms
FROM permissions
GROUP BY user_id
```

...but obviously, some magical "bitwise-or" function instead of SUM. Anyone know of anything like that?

(And for bonus points, does it work in oracle?)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

MySQL:

```
SELECT user_id, BIT_OR(permissions) as all_perms
FROM permissions
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: As always, MySQL kicks oracle's ass.

Answer (score 9):

*Ah, another one of those questions where I find the answer 5 minutes after asking... Accepted answer will go to the MySQL implementation though...*

Here's how to do it with Oracle, as I discovered on [Radino's blog](http://radino.eu/2008/05/31/bitwise-or-aggregate-function/)

You create an object...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE bitor_impl AS OBJECT
(
  bitor NUMBER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(ctx IN OUT bitor_impl) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(SELF  IN OUT bitor_impl,
                                       VALUE IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(SELF IN OUT bitor_impl,
                                     ctx2 IN bitor_impl) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(SELF        IN OUT bitor_impl,
                                         returnvalue OUT NUMBER,
                                         flags       IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY bitor_impl IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(ctx IN OUT bitor_impl) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := bitor_impl(0);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END ODCIAggregateInitialize;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(SELF  IN OUT bitor_impl,
                                       VALUE IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.bitor := SELF.bitor + VALUE - bitand(SELF.bitor, VALUE);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END ODCIAggregateIterate;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(SELF IN OUT bitor_impl,
                                     ctx2 IN bitor_impl) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.bitor := SELF.bitor + ctx2.bitor - bitand(SELF.bitor, ctx2.bitor);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END ODCIAggregateMerge;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(SELF        IN OUT bitor_impl,
                                         returnvalue OUT NUMBER,
                                         flags       IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    returnvalue := SELF.bitor;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END ODCIAggregateTerminate;
END;
/
```

...and then [define your own aggregate function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bitoragg(x IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
PARALLEL_ENABLE
AGGREGATE USING bitor_impl;
/
```

Usage:

```
SELECT user_id, bitoragg(permissions) FROM perms GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: you deserve a bigger cookie

Answer (score 2):

And you can do a bitwise or with...

```
FUNCTION BITOR(x IN NUMBER, y IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN x + y - BITAND(x,y);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to know the possible permission components (1, 2 and 4) apriori (thus harder to maintain), but this is pretty simple and would work:

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(BITAND(permissions, 1)) +
       MAX(BITAND(permissions, 2)) +
       MAX(BITAND(permissions, 4)) all_perms
FROM permissions
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested to find all users who
>   have a particular flag set (eg: write)
>   on ANY record

What's wrong with simply

```
SELECT DISTINCT User_ID
FROM Permissions
WHERE permissions & 2 = 2
```

Comment: I think its not working (on oracle). The operator & is not defined. Use bitand instead.

Comment: @Christian13467: I don't know oracle but I assume the where clause could simply become *WHERE bitand(permissions, 2) = 2*?

Comment: yeah ok - so i worded the example poorly... doing an aggregate bitwise OR is more useful in my actual situation.