# Bitwise OR among results

Tags: mysql, bitwise-or

I'm wondering if it's possible to do a bitwise OR among MySQL query. I have a query like:

```
SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE `code`='4'
```

It returns an array of values, but I want a unique value with the **bitwise** OR of all values. Is is possible from MySQL or should I delegate to PHP?

I.e. The query above returns this list of values:

```
value
-----
1
5
4
2
7
8
```

And I want as a result the OR of these values 1 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 7 | 8 = 15

Comment: Duplicate or similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397913/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-bitwise-group-function

Comment: SQL queries do _not_ return "arrays".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(@r:=@r|value) FROM `table`, (SELECT @r:=0) x
```

Jim.H's suggestion is much better. Thanks!

```
SELECT BIT_OR(value) FROM `table`
```

Comment: Clever, but eww. `SELECT bit_or(value) FROM table;`